# Sorting dictionary list-values based on time

Tags: python, list, sorting, date, dictionary

I'm pretty new to python (couple weeks into it) and I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around data structures. What I've done so far is extract text line-by-line from a .txt file and store them into a dictionary with the key as animal, for example.

```
database = {
    'dog': ['apple', 'dog', '2012-06-12-08-12-59'],
    'cat': [
        ['orange', 'cat', '2012-06-11-18-33-12'],
        ['blue', 'cat', '2012-06-13-03-23-48']
    ],
    'frog': ['kiwi', 'frog', '2012-06-12-17-12-44'],
    'cow': [
        ['pear', 'ant', '2012-06-12-14-02-30'],
        ['plum', 'cow', '2012-06-12-23-27-14']
    ]
} 

# year-month-day-hour-min-sec
```

That way, when I print my dictionary out, it prints out by animal types, and the newest dates first.

Whats the best way to go about sorting this data by time? I'm on python 2.7. What I'm thinking is

for each key:

grab the list (or list of lists) --> get the 3rd entry --> `'-'.split` it,  --> then maybe try the `sorted(parameters)`

I'm just not really sure how to go about this...

Comment: That data structure was broken. Hopefully my fix was what you meant? Also dont use `dict` as a name. Its a builtin

Comment: The dates don't need converting - they'll sort naturally as they are

Comment: Thanks jdi! Yeah, your edit was what I meant to have. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Now, is it really variable structure like that where some animals have only a single level list and some have nested lists?

Comment: @jdi makes a very good point - was this an oversight in your example or does it reflect your actual data?

Comment: Yes, some of my values are nested lists and some are just a single level list

Comment: But do you have control over this data? Are you able to keep it consistently list-of-lists?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by having control over this data. The data can change depending on the environment if this is what you mean. I would like to take the case that only one 'animal' populates in the data. But with the data I have at the moment, it is list of lists consistently.

Comment: It's ok to have just a single list inside a list. It will make your life much easier if the structure is consistent

Comment: No what I am saying is that I am assuming you are building this data structure yourself. If thats the case, you can always make `d[animal]` be a list of lists even if its only one list

Comment: I see - thanks for clearing that up for me jdi and gnibbler. I am indeed building this data structure myself. Because I only have one list and making this into a list of lists - does this mean i will have an empty list accompanying the single list?

Comment: No, you will just have a list that contains only one list as opposed to multiple lists:  `[['foo']]`

Comment: Understood. I appreciate you staying and going through the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Walk through the elements of your dictionary.  For each value, run `sorted` on your list of lists, and tell the sorting algorithm to use the third field of the list as the "key" element.  This key element is what is used to compare values to other elements in the list in order to ascertain sort order.  To tell `sorted` which element of your lists to sort with, use `operator.itemgetter` to specify the third element.

Since your timestamps are rigidly structured and each character in the timestamp is more temporally significant than the next one, you can sort them naturally, like strings - you don't need to convert them to times.

```
# Dictionary stored in d
from operator import itemgetter
# Iterate over the elements of the dictionary; below, by
# calling items(), k gets the key value of an entry and 
# v gets the value of that entry
for k,v in d.items():
    if v and isinstance(v[0], list):
        v.sort(key=itemgetter(2)) # Start with 0, so third element is 2
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what k,v are. I've seen some code similar to this but never an explanation.

Comment: @user1443368 I've amended my answer to elaborate a bit.

Comment: There is a problem with this solution. It doesn't account for the single lists and messes up their orders: `'dog': ['2012-06-12-08-12-59', 'dog', 'apple']`

Comment: @jdi Whoops, I didn't notice some of the values were not nested lists.  Astute observation.

Comment: Quick fix: just add a test before the sort: `if v and isinstance(v[0], list):`

Comment: Also, you can just do an in-place `d[k].sort(...)` which I think is more efficient since you don't have to create temporary lists on the fly.

Comment: @jdi Good points.  I am loathe to accomodate the list vs list-in-list variability, just because I don't want to promote the inconsistent data structure, but it does solve the problem here.  Thanks!

Comment: Thats true. Ideally the OP will correct the data structure and then apply this. Maybe update the inplace sort though?

Comment: @jdi Wow, you're fast - yes, I just chose to amend the post after I made my comment, not before.  :)

Comment: I use an array of 6 monitors to watch multiple areas of StackOverflow at the same time, like a stock exchange...jk ;-) But yes, really I do.

Comment: @jdi Thanks for fixing my other mistake, too.  You are on the ball!

Answer (score 3):

If your dates are all in the format `year-month-day-hour-min-sec`,`2012-06-12-23-27-14`,I think your step of split it is not necessary,just compare them as string.

```
>>> '2012-06-12-23-27-14' > '2012-06-12-14-02-30'                              
True
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's interesting. I didn't know you could determine greater or less than with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you'll probably want each key,value item in the dict to be of a similar type. At the moment some of them (eg: database['dog'] ) are a list of strings (a line) and some (eg: database['cat']) are a list of lines. If you get them all into list of lines format (even if there's only one item in the list of lines) it will be much easier.

Then, one (old) way would be to make a comparison function for those lines. This will be easy since your dates are already in a format that's directly (string) comparable. To compare two lines, you want to compare the 3rd (2nd index) item in them:

```
def compare_line_by_date(x,y):
    return cmp(x[2],y[2])
```

Finally you can get the lines for a particular key sorted by telling the `sorted` builtin to use your compare_line_by_date function:

```
sorted(database['cat'],compare_line_by_date)
```

The above is suitable (but slow, and will disappear in python 3) for arbitrarily complex comparison/sorting functions. There are other ways to do your particular sort, for example by using the `key` parameter of sorted:

```
def key_for_line(line):
    return line[2]

sorted(database['cat'],key=key_for_line)
```

Using keys for sorting is much faster than cmp because the key function only needs to be run once per item in the list to be sorted, instead of every time items in the list are compared (which is usually much more often than the number of items in the list). The idea of a key is to basically boil each list item down into something that be compared naturally, like a string or a number. In the example above we boiled the line down into just the date, which is then compared.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested any of the code in this answer... but it should work!

Comment: Just to point out, using a cmp function is significantly slower than a key function.

Comment: Please don't go telling people to use `cmp` with `sorted`. It's deprecated for a reason

Comment: @gnibbler are you talking about not using the cmp parameter (which I think must be needed) or the cmp in the underlying comparision function? _is_ it deprecated in 2.7? the docs dont mention that.

Comment: @jdi yep, you are right. I guess the main thing is to show the OP, who's still learning python, a way to make arbitrary comparison functions, rather than just a comparison function for the particular stated case. using the key parameter for arbitrary functions requires one extra step of logic here which might draw out the answer too much.

Comment: @chees: Note the docs refer to the [`cmp` sort as the old sort](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#The_Old_Way_Using_the_cmp_Parameter) and that it was removed in python 3.x. And as for teaching the arbitrary cmp function, I believe the preference now is to define comparison operator functions on your custom classes instead of an old cmp function. So in this case, its not really helpful to present it as an option.

Comment: @gnibbler i did some research and i see it's been removed in python 3, for good reason. i may as well add this info in here though noone will look at my answer anyway :)

Comment: I will definitely go through this answer and the string comparison answer as it will help me understand python better. Being new to python its sometimes hard for me to figure a way to do things. Here, you all have provided me several options which will help me understand different ways to do the same thing. Thanks for your input.